# How to generate documentation using Sandcastle NuGet package (EWSoftware.SHFB)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, sandcastle

I am trying to generate website documentation for my C# code using the NuGet package of Sandcastle in Visual Studio (EWSoftware.SHFB). The fact is that I don't know how to use it. I install it from the NuGet package manager and then I have no idea what to do with it.

I have no problem to edit my documentation project and to generate the corresponding website using the VS Sandcaslte extension installed with the default installer.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This might also be helpful. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82430/Authoring-Integrating-API-Help-for-VS-and-VS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MsBuild.exe MyDocumentationProject.shfbproj` generated the documentation. It means that the project can not be edited via VS, but it can be generated using the command line.

Beforhand, as stated at https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB/blob/master/NuGet/ReadMe.txt:

1. the `ComponentPath` property must be set in `MyDocumentationProject.shfbproj` to provide reflection information regarding the framework you are using.

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
     <ComponentPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\packages\EWSoftware.SHFB.NETFramework.4.6</ComponentPath>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```
2. The SHFB environment variable must be set conditionally in `MyDocumentationProject.shfbproj`.

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
     <SHFBROOT Condition=" '$(SHFBROOT)' == '' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\packages\EWSoftware.SHFB.2015.10.10.0\Tools\</SHFBROOT>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```

Comment: How is the project built after adding these properties? I have a .NET library project where I included these EWSoftware.SHFB nuget packages, but no help files are generated when I build this project.

Comment: Just have same issue, but the problem was in duplicate <ComponentPath />, do not forget to delete it.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you already have a solution with a project, add a new project of type 'Documentation' to your solution.

[image]

Right-click Documentation Sources and add a source by selecting the csproj you wish to document.

[image]

Then just build.

Comment: I want users that don't have the Sandcatle component installed to be able to  generate the documentation.

Comment: What software would generate that documentation in that scenario?

Comment: As stated at https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB/blob/master/NuGet/ReadMe.txt, the NuGet package should provide such a functionnality.

Comment: I could be wrong because I never did this, but as I understand from the readme, the NuGet package provides the same functionality (referred to as Sandcastle Help File Builder), but it is installed through NuGet instead of running sandcastle.msi.

Comment: I have uninstalled Sandcastle from the Windows Uninstaller, I have uninstalled the VS Sandcastle extension from VS and I have downloaded the NuGet package from VS. The behaviour is not the same...

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: Thre is no way to create/edit/build SHFB project from the VS GUI. However there is a Sandcastle installation in the NuGet packages folder of the solution. I might have to run special commands as post-build events of a project.

Answer (score 1):

I created the documentation project with the Visual Studio plug-in after installing Sandcastle.

I added the following post-build event on another project when completed successfully:

```
IF "$(ConfigurationName)"=="Debug" Goto Exit

ECHO Building SHFB help file via MSBuild
"$(SystemRoot)\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"  /p:CleanIntermediates=True /p:Configuration=Release "$(SolutionDir)Documentation\Documentation.shfbproj"

:Exit
```

The SHFB environment variable in the project documentation file looks like this:

```
<!-- NOTE: Update the version number in the path (YYYY.M.D.R) to match the package version -->
<SHFBROOT Condition=" '$(SHFBROOT)' == '' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\packages\EWSoftware.SHFB.2016.9.17.0\tools\</SHFBROOT>
```

If Sandcastle isn't installed on the system, it'll use the executables from the NuGet package. Make sure the version matches for others.

These documentation links might help for issues I forgot about:

- [Building Projects Outside the GUI](https://ewsoftware.github.io/SHFB/html/8ffc0d37-0215-4609-b6f8-dba53a6c5063.htm)
- [Generating Documentation with Team Build](https://ewsoftware.github.io/SHFB/html/ec822059-b179-4add-984d-485580050ffb.htm)