# Documentation project type missing after NuGet Sandcastle Install

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package, sandcastle

I have installed the most current version of Sandcastle from NuGet (EWSoftware.SHFB version 2015.10.10.0), and the needed Reflection package (EWSoftware.SHFB.NETFramework version 4.6).

[image: Sandcastle is installed]

I read @Frank-Rem answer to Numid's question [How to generate documentation using Sandcastle NuGet package (EWSoftware.SHFB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668365/how-to-generate-documentation-using-sandcastle-nuget-package-ewsoftware-shfb) and tried to add a new project to my solution. However, when I try to add a Sandcastle Documentation project I do not have the Documentation project type as an option.

[image: Sandcastle project type is missing]

I uninstalled the NuGet package and reinstalled it, thinking it may have been a buggy install.  But the documentation project type is still not an option, even after shutting Visual Studio down and relaunching it.

I read through the readme.txt file and saw that I will need to add some property tags to the .shfbproj file when it gets generated.  Beyond that, I don't see any other steps that I need to perform or packages to install in order to get the project type to show up. I have also gone to the [GitHub project page](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB/issues) and checked the Issues tab to make sure this isn’t a known issue they are working on.

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.

Are there additional steps I need to take to get the Sandcastle project type to show up in the Add New Project list?

Thank you for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by running the [Sandcastle Help File Builder Guided Installer](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB/releases). This identified missing components and installed them.

I was then able to follow the instructions from @frank-rem on [adding the documentation project and documentation source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668365/how-to-generate-documentation-using-sandcastle-nuget-package-ewsoftware-shfb) to the new project.

> Assuming that you already have a solution with a project, add a new project of type 'Documentation' to your solution.
>
> Right-click Documentation Sources and add a source by selecting the csproj you wish to document.
>
> Then just build.

*Additional steps I took to get a finalized help doc:* I found that Sandcastle had added several TODO items, which didn't show up in the Visual Studio task list.  So I did a search on the solution for TODO and resolved them that way.

After that I followed the instructions on [adding the namespace summaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156582/namespace-documentation-on-a-net-project-sandcastle) provided by @davy-landman (in a comment to Davy Landman's answer) to clear up some missing flags.

> This has actually changed in the latest version (currently 1.9.3.0) to Project Properties > Summaries > NameSpaceSummaries. – Ant Swift Jan 6 '12 at 9:44